# I am trying to recreate a clustered column chart made in Excel

Tags: r

I made a clustered column chart on excel which looked like this:

[image]

(the X axis is split into two categories and within them are two subcategories presented on two separate bars).
And I am trying to recreate it on R. So far, I have taken the raw data and made this table on r:

| Age | MolLayer% | GranLayer% |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Immature | 6 | 12 |
| Mature | 7 | 12.5 |

Since I have done this on excel, I know this is all of the data I need for the graph

I am now struggling to format the chart so it looks the same as the one on excel. What are the steps to forming the chart on R?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can go with this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)


"Age    MolLayer%   GranLayer%
Immature    6   12
Mature  7   12.5" |> 
  read_tsv() |> 
  # transform the data for the ggplot
  pivot_longer(names_to = "key",
               values_to = "value",
               cols = -Age) |> 
  ggplot(aes(key, value, fill = Age)) +
  # not a stacked plot but arranged next to each other
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  # make white background
  theme_light() +
  # add bar colors
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#3232ff", "#9898ff")) +
  # add description
  labs(title = "Proportion of Cellular Layers Compared to the Total Length from\nFolium to White Matter",
       x = "Layer",
       y = "Percentage of Total Distance Taken Up by Each Layer") +
  # center title to middle
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Output is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How could I alter lines 6-14 so I can use data from a data frame I've created in R?